# My category's +load isn't getting called, but only in an archive build

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on a static library that includes several categories defined for classes outside the library. I use the `+load` method on the categories to perform some class initialization. This works fine for debug and release builds, but when I build and archive for ad-hoc testing or app store distribution, none of the categories' `+load` methods get called.

I am linking all of my libraries and the app that uses them with the `-ObjC` and `-all_load` flags and like I said, everything works correctly in both debug and release builds that are loaded onto a device through Xcode. It's only when I load an archive build through iTunes that I have trouble.

Does anybody have any ideas what could be going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like this is due to a bug in Xcode 4.3. When I compile with Xcode 4.2, then everything works correctly.